# Play store wrong when it claims that this app is incompatible with all of your devices

Tags: android, google-play

So, I have an app release to a closed beta testing. There is a device, for which:

1. Google Play Developer Console claims support
2. Google Play Listing (available for beta testers only) claims no support

Update: OK, so people don't like "what the heck" questions, but the question really is - how is this possible? How to fix it? Google Play listing device compatibility indication is clearly wrong and since Google offers no support, the only way is to seek community help, which is what I'm doing.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: So, what do you actually want to know. You probably understand that 'What the heck?' is not a really valuable question for this community

Comment: How is this possible?
What to check?
Where to look for?

To me, "what the heck" is a perfectly reasonable question when a system does something it's not supposed to do.

Comment: Perhaps for you it is, but be aware that this community contains more members than just you. For other users it might not be as logical as you think, let alone what you expect from other users. Still, also after stating your question better, I'd have a look at the post commented by CommonsWare

Comment: Yes, I checked the thread referenced above and I strongly disagree. I'd be happy to ask Google's "customer support"...if these was one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, one cannot install his own paid app. At all. And the error message, instead of saying this, just says that the app is incompatible with all your devices.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, pretty much by trial and error. It does not make any sense, but it works. The moment I changed it from "paid" to "free", Google Play Store Listing realized that it is compatible with my device.

Go figure.